# How to configure npm pug-php-filter with gulp?

Tags: php, html, npm, gulp, pug

I cannot figure out how to configure pug-php-filter(https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-php-filter) with gulp so that i can use php in pug file.
Plz help me with this.

Comment: What does this package do?

Comment: what i simply know about this is that, it let us use php in pug file. but i cant figure out how to configure it in gulp for livereload and all :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var pug = require('gulp-pug'),
    pugPHPFilter = require('pug-php-filter');

gulp.task('pug', function() {
  return gulp.src('./_pugfiles/**/*.pug')
   .pipe( pug({
       pretty: "\t",
       filters: {
        php: pugPHPFilter
    }
}) )
   .pipe(rename(function (path) {
      path.extname = ".php"
    }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./site'));

});
```